# How to Force the NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert to use another Tableview than the one used by the tableviewcontroller?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an Application where I am making 2 Tableview Vertical One Which is the one used by the Tableviewcontroller , & in each section  I have 1 row where I have created another Horizontal  tableview inside  , When I add a ManagedObject in a "AddItemViewController" , the ManagedObject is saved Correctly , although when the NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert is called whithin the tableviewcontroller  , it is using the vertical tableview to be updated , not the horizontal .

I am missing Something , but I can't Figure it out , Any Help ?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` delegate method (where `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` would be used), though I can not follow the rest of the question.  That delegate method represents a FRC, nothing about a specific table view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this Problem by performing a Fetch request in the MainViewController , passed it to a NSMutableArray , then Use in the Other Tableview , Do my Changes , Then the NSManagedObjectContext, &Send a Notification to the MainViewController , to Reload the Table View Data Again

Answer (score 0):

Actually , the NSFetchresultschangeinsert in the below code :

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    HorizontalTableCell *fuck=[[HorizontalTableCell alloc]init];
    UITableView *tableView= fuck.horizontalTableView;
    //UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    //newIndexPath.section==indexPath.section;
    //NSLog(@"The Type of the Fetched %d",i);

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

This code is by default there in the Apple Default CoreData , UItableViewController